# Android Loaders lifecycle, or: will onStopLoading() always called before onReset()?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

Could there be a case in which `onReset()` is called without calling `onStopLoading()` directly before it?

More generally, I'm trying to figure out the Loader's life-cycle, a-la the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) chart, and which `onSomething()`s run inside which state(s) of the Activity's/Fragment's lifecycle state.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,`onReset()` can get called without a preceding call to `onStopLoading()`.
The implementation of `onStopLoading()` has to make sure that no loads get triggered after then while the implementation of `onReset()` should do that AND free resources if not already freed. `onStartLoading()` has to be able to start/resume from both states.

Therefore it seems to be good practice to call `onStopLoading()` in `onReset()`'s implementation as the example code on the [AsyncTaskLoader reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) does.